# 'float' object has no attribute 'rint'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

All the cells of DataFrame are of float type but still it is not able to round off.

**DataFrame**

[image]

**Dtype**
[image]

I am doing this:

```
df_lmsd['LMSD']=np.around(df_lmsd['LMSD'],2)
df_lmsd['LMSD(#)']=np.around(df_lmsd['LMSD(#)'],2)
df_lmsd
```

Output:-
[image]

Python Version:- Python 3.10.9
Ide:- Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Check the output of `df_lmsd.info()`. I think you have the LMSD columns represented with type `object` rather than `float`. Notice that `100.0` has only 1 decimal place, while the others have more.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have the LMSD columns stored as the type `object` rather than `float`. To demonstrate this, I have reproduced the error.

---

##### Input Data (with the LMSD columns stored as type `float`)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    "created_date": ["2023-03-01", "2023-03-03", "2023-03-07", "2023-03-08", "2023-03-09"],
    "lmsd": [99.701135, 100.0, 4.142565, 14.182277, 24.433356],
    "lmsd_hash": [99.853902, 100.0, 4.579792, 14.58302, 23.937297]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the dates to datetime objects
df["created_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["created_date"])

print(df)
```

```
  created_date        lmsd   lmsd_hash
0   2023-03-01   99.701135   99.853902
1   2023-03-03  100.000000  100.000000
2   2023-03-07    4.142565    4.579792
3   2023-03-08   14.182277   14.583020
4   2023-03-09   24.433356   23.937297
```

Output of `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------        --------------  -----         
 0   created_date  5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   lmsd          5 non-null      float64       
 2   lmsd_hash     5 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2)
memory usage: 248.0 bytes
```

---

##### Storing the LMSD columns as type `object`

```py
# Represent the LMSD columns as objects
df[["lmsd", "lmsd_hash"]] = df[["lmsd", "lmsd_hash"]].astype(object)

print(df)
```

```
  created_date       lmsd  lmsd_hash
0   2023-03-01  99.701135  99.853902
1   2023-03-03      100.0      100.0
2   2023-03-07   4.142565   4.579792
3   2023-03-08  14.182277   14.58302
4   2023-03-09  24.433356  23.937297
```

(Notice how this matches your DataFrame)

Output of `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------        --------------  -----         
 0   created_date  5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   lmsd          5 non-null      object        
 2   lmsd_hash     5 non-null      object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
```

---

##### Attempting to round `object` columns:

```py
# Try to round the values in the LMSD columns (represented as objects)
df['lmsd']  = np.around(df['lmsd'], 2)
df['lmsd_hash']  = np.around(df['lmsd_hash'], 2)
```

The following error is produced, matching the one you were given:

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method
```

---

##### Representing the columns as `float` before rounding

To fix this, ensure that the LMSD columns are stored as floats before rounding, using the [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype) method:

```py
# Convert the LMSD columns to float values.
df[["lmsd", "lmsd_hash"]] = df[["lmsd", "lmsd_hash"]].astype(float)

# Round the values to two decimal places
df['lmsd']  = np.around(df['lmsd'], 2)
df['lmsd_hash']  = np.around(df['lmsd_hash'], 2)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  created_date    lmsd  lmsd_hash
0   2023-03-01   99.70      99.85
1   2023-03-03  100.00     100.00
2   2023-03-07    4.14       4.58
3   2023-03-08   14.18      14.58
4   2023-03-09   24.43      23.94
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_lmsd = pd.DataFrame({'LMSD': [1.23456789], 'LMSD(#)': [2.34567890]})

df_lmsd['LMSD'] = np.around(np.array(df_lmsd['LMSD']), 2)
df_lmsd['LMSD(#)'] = np.around(np.array(df_lmsd['LMSD(#)']), 2)

print(df_lmsd)
```

which gives

```
   LMSD  LMSD(#)
0  1.23     2.35
```